# Estou com problemas para exibir a view do meu projeto JSF -

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

não aparece nenhum erro e a tela fica em branco. Acredito que não deva ser nada muito complexo de se resolver mas sou novo nessa linguagem e estou tendo dificuldade para entender a sintaxe.

Na view criar_grupo.xhtml:

```
        <p:outputLabel value="Apelido: "  />

        <p:inputText value="#{sessao.g.nome}" id="edNomeGrupo" />  <br/>


        <p:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{sessao.cadastrar()}" />
</h:form>
```

no bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Sessao implements Serializable {

    List<Grupo> grupos;
    Grupo g;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{aplicacao}")
    Aplicacao app;

    public Sessao() {

        grupos = new LinkedList<Grupo>();
        g = new Grupo();
    }

    public String cadastrar() {
        grupos.add(g);
        g = new Grupo();

       app.adicinarRegistros(grupos);

        return null;
    }
```

vou postar o outro bean tbm:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Aplicacao {

private List<Grupo> registrados;

List<SelectItem> gruposSelecao;

public Aplicacao() {
        registrados = new LinkedList<Grupo>();
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getGruposSelecao(){

        if(gruposSelecao == null){

            gruposSelecao = new LinkedList<>();

            for(Grupo c: registrados){

                gruposSelecao.add(new SelectItem(c, c.getNome()));
            }

        }

        return gruposSelecao;
    }


  public void adicinarRegistros(List<Grupo> novos) {
        registrados.addAll( novos );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que está ocorrendo NullPointer. Cria um método init() e anota como @PostConstrut. No método init() você instancia seu atributo g.

```
@PostContruct
private void init() {
    g = new Grupo();
}
```

Se não resolver posta tua view completa para podermos ajudar.